# mongoose setting key as variable

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema which I'd like to have the key be the current timestamp:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Entries = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: false,
    timeStamp: {
        data: Schema.Types.Mixed
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entries', Entries);
```

How could I make timestamp be dynamic and pick up `new Date();` each time it is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Date` SchemaType and set a `default` of `Date.now`:

```
var Entries = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: false,
    timeStamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

See the example `updated` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).